# How to use regular expression to match any thing not in the a list?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list I want to not match, say: 123, 456 and 78

```
If the the text is "456", no match.
if the text is "123;456", no match
if the text is "123;78", no match
if the text is "123;34", match
if the text is "56", match
```

So as long as the text has any item not in the list, then it's match.

The closest I can come up is:

```
^(?!(;)?(?:123|456|78)(;)?$).*$
```

But it fails for "123;456".

So what's the correct regex to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Which regex form? This is possible with PCRE, but not BRE or ERE (which don't support negative assertions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Actually it is possible with extended regular expressions. A basic fact of computer science is that the class of regular languages is closed under negation. That doesn't mean that it's convenient to express as an ERE but it's possible.

Comment: Granted, "possible" was not the right word. I'll be happy with any readers substituting "practical".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, it's highly impractical in general to negate regular expressions. I don't recommend it in any case, but I did give an answer showing that it's possible. (There may be some deeper reason here, I hate to second-guess those asking questions.)

Comment: @ongahong What language are you using? That will inform whether PCRE is available or not.

Comment: Why is `123;34` a match?

Comment: @dawg, because 34 is not an item in the list.

Comment: But 123 is an item in the list

Comment: as long as the text has any item not in the list, then it's match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is not completely clear, I made several assumptions based on your examples.

- I assume each item in the list is a non-empty sequence of decimal digits; specifically a match to the following:

  ```
  [0-9]+
  ```
- I assume the items of the list are separated by a single `;` character; no other leading or terminating characters or whitespace are allowed anywhere in the input.

I break this down into three portions:

1. Any leading item, whether or not it's in the list:

   ```
   (?:[0-9]+;)*
   ```
2. One required item which is not in the list:

   ```
   (?:(?!(123|456|78)\b)[0-9]+)
   ```
3. Any trailing items, whether or not they are in the list:

   ```
   (?:;[0-9]+)*
   ```

Combining them we get the final result:

```
^(?:[0-9]+;)*(?:(?!(123|456|78)\b)[0-9]+)(?:;[0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Works pretty well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be: match any string of characters unless it is of the form "x;y;...;z" with x, y, z, etc. one of 123, 456, and 78.

I believe this regular expression will do the trick:

```
^(..?;)*([^147]|1[^2]|4[^5]|7[^8]|12[^3]|45[^6]|[14]$|12$|45$)
```

Remember: just because regular expressions *can* do something (like negate a regular expression) doesn't mean they *should* be used to do that thing. In this case you should probably explode the string on `;` and check each term until you find a non-match.

Comment: Since it's unlikely that his list is hard-coded, can you show how to generalize this from an arbitrary list?

Comment: @Barmar: I hope to discourage people from using regular expressions to parse the negations of lists. In general the best way I know is to convert the regular expression to a NFA, convert that to a DFA, swap accepting and rejecting paths, and convert back to a regular expression. I don't remember if this has exponential blowup or double-exponential, probably the latter. Bad news in either case.

Comment: Thanks, but my list is actually much bigger with more than 100 items. How to do that? I don't really care about performance.

Comment: @ongahong: I strongly recommend you explode/split the list on semicolons, then check each element against your list (binary search). I do give a comment above outlining the general technique for negating a regex but it's not a good idea for lots of reasons -- for one, the size of the regex can become enormous.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for your help! But our requirement won't allow to explode/split the list. We have to use one single regex to process it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use word boundaries:

```
\b(?!(?:123|456|78))[^;\n]+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE3yE4/2)

Comment: THat's not true, `4567` does match as per [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE3yE4/1) using this regex.

Comment: Thank. But I tried using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and 4567 is no match. Aso I am using C# regex, it's also no match. 999;123;234 should be match since 999 and 234 are not in the list.

Comment: How can `999;123;234` be a match when one of the blocked number `123` is in the list?

Comment: See the example in my op(as long as the text has any item not in the list, then it's match). If the text is "123;34", match since 34 is not in the list.

Comment: check updated answer and linked demo. This will work for C# also.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I'm sure we will get to the bottom of this.

These updated regexes are the *maximum* throw of coverage available.
They use the standard fast un-roll method. As the requirements become more clear,
start deleting substrings and/or modifiers as needed, ultimately keeping the same
overall structure.

Good Luck!

```
 # ======================================================
 # Sample contains any chars
 # @"^(?s)(?!;*(?:123|456|78)(?:;+(?:123|456|78))*;*$).+$"

 ^  
 (?s)
 (?!
      ;*
      (?: 123 | 456 | 78 )
      (?:
           ;+ 
           (?: 123 | 456 | 78 )
      )*
      ;*
      $ 
 )
 .+ 
 $ 

 # ======================================================
 # Sample contains semi-colon and digits only
 # @"^(?!;*(?:123|456|78)(?:;+(?:123|456|78))*;*$)[;0-9]+$"

 ^ 
 (?!
      ;*
      (?: 123 | 456 | 78 )
      (?:
           ;+
           (?: 123 | 456 | 78 )
      )*
      ;*
      $ 
 )
 [;0-9]+ 
 $
```

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work for input "123;456;78".